# django-paypal does not have signal for subscr_payment

Tags: django, paypal, django-paypal

I was looking into django-paypal IPN source code and I realized that it does not have a signal for subscr_payment transaction type.

Can I just assume that if I receive a subscr_signup IPN message, the payment was successful?

my signal handler

```
def subscription_succesful(sender, **kwargs):
ipn_obj = sender

if ipn_obj.payment_status == "Completed":
    user = User.objects.get(pk=ipn_obj.custom)
    business = Business.objects.get(user=user)
    business.active = True
    business.save()

subscription_signup.connect(subscription_succesful)
```

This is currently not working because ipn_obj.payment_status is not sent in a subscr_signup IPN message.

Answer (score 0):

I have just integrated the subscription paypal modulec using Django Paypal. 
The payment status is complete and it calls the following IPN signals subscription_signup and recurring_payment signal for subscr_payment.
However still working on it and having issues notifying paypal back that all the signal have been received.Are you getting duplicate signals from paypal after making payment?

Answer (score 0):

I know your post is very old. `payment_status` is not valid tag for subcription.

```
def subscription_succesful(sender, **kwargs):
  ipn_obj = sender

  if ipn_obj.txn_type == "subscr_signup":
    user = User.objects.get(pk=ipn_obj.custom)
    business = Business.objects.get(user=user)
    business.active = True
    business.save()

 subscription_signup.connect(subscription_succesful)
```